# How does Robot's Telnet library work?

Tags: python, testing, robotframework

I've been taking a look at Robot's Telnet library(https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/src/robot/libraries/Telnet.py) and I haven't found an answer in the documentation to this question.

I get that The Telnet object handles opening and closing of TelnetConnections, and stores the current connection.  But when something like write is called, how does Robot know to call Telnet._conn.write()?

For example:

```
Open connection  192.254.64.3
Open connection  192.254.64.4
Write            This goes to the second IP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet library uses some introspection magic, supported by RF dynamic library interface.

When Telnet library is taken into use, `get_keyword_names` is called. This inspects also the `TelnetConnection` class for it's own methods and registers  these as keywords. During execution RF calls e.g. `Telnet.write`, which is handled by the `__getattr__` method, which in turn calls the corresponding method of the underlying `TelnetConnection`.

This whole mechanism is implemented in lines 308-240.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I forgot that __getattr__() returned the function object and not just the name.